# Java: Outlined Text - thick stroke causes gaps

Tags: java, fonts, shapes

I'm trying to give a pretty thick stroke to some text and doing so gives me gaps around certain characters such as 'i' and '.'

[image: VALUE_STROKE_PURE]
[image: VALUE_FRACTIONALMETRICS_OFF_VALUE_STROKE_DEFAULT]

I've tried all the permutations of RenderingHints.KEY_STROKE_CONTROL and KEY_FRACTIONALMETRICS (the only two which seem to have any bearing on this (other than KEY_ANTIALIASING and KEY_RENDERING). I've tried approaching this both with a TextLayout and a GlyphVector. I'm at a loss not on how to proceed. Ideally, I'd like to get this working using VALUE_STROKE_PURE, since that gives the most smooth results, but also ends up with the largest gaps. Any help would be appreciated!

```
public class TestLabelImage 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        BufferedImage labelImg = getTextAsBmp("testing.", 
                                              Color.BLACK, 
                                              Color.WHITE, 
                                              "TimesRoman", 
                                              Font.PLAIN, 
                                              36, 
                                              18.0f);       
    }


     static public void setRenderingHings(Graphics2D g2d)
     {
         g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
         g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_RENDERING, RenderingHints.VALUE_RENDER_QUALITY);

         //g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ALPHA_INTERPOLATION, RenderingHints.VALUE_ALPHA_INTERPOLATION_QUALITY);
         //g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
         //g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_COLOR_RENDERING, RenderingHints.VALUE_COLOR_RENDER_QUALITY);
         //g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_DITHERING, RenderingHints.VALUE_DITHER_ENABLE);
         //g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_FRACTIONALMETRICS, RenderingHints.VALUE_FRACTIONALMETRICS_ON);
         //g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_INTERPOLATION, RenderingHints.VALUE_INTERPOLATION_BILINEAR);
         //g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_RENDERING, RenderingHints.VALUE_RENDER_QUALITY);
         //g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_STROKE_CONTROL, RenderingHints.VALUE_STROKE_DEFAULT);
         //g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_STROKE_CONTROL, RenderingHints.VALUE_STROKE_NORMALIZE);
         g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_STROKE_CONTROL, RenderingHints.VALUE_STROKE_PURE);
    }


    static public BufferedImage getTextAsBmp(String text, Color textColor, Color textOutlineColor, String font, int style, int size, float stroke)
    {
         //create a temporary image so we can make use of Graphics class
         BufferedImage img = new BufferedImage(1, 1, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
         Graphics2D g2d = img.createGraphics();
         setRenderingHings(g2d);

         Font f = new Font(font, style, size);
         FontMetrics metrics = g2d.getFontMetrics(f);   

         //Option 1:
         TextLayout textTl = new TextLayout(text, f, g2d.getFontRenderContext());
         Shape outline = textTl.getOutline(null);

         //Option 2:
         //GlyphVector glyphVector = f.createGlyphVector(g2d.getFontRenderContext(), text);
         //Shape outline = glyphVector.getOutline();

         g2d.dispose();

         //create a new image to the calculated height and width
         img = new BufferedImage((int)(outline.getBounds().getWidth() + stroke), (int)(outline.getBounds().getHeight() + stroke), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);

         g2d = img.createGraphics();
         setRenderingHings(g2d);

         g2d.setColor(Color.RED);
         g2d.fillRect(0,0,img.getWidth(),img.getHeight());

         g2d.translate((img.getWidth()/2 - outline.getBounds().getWidth()/2), outline.getBounds().getHeight() + (stroke)/2 - metrics.getDescent()); 

         g2d.setColor(textOutlineColor);
         //g2d.setStroke(new BasicStroke(stroke, BasicStroke.CAP_BUTT, BasicStroke.JOIN_BEVEL));
         //g2d.setStroke(new BasicStroke(stroke, BasicStroke.CAP_BUTT, BasicStroke.JOIN_MITER));
         //g2d.setStroke(new BasicStroke(stroke, BasicStroke.CAP_BUTT, BasicStroke.JOIN_ROUND));
         //g2d.setStroke(new BasicStroke(stroke, BasicStroke.CAP_ROUND, BasicStroke.JOIN_BEVEL));
         //g2d.setStroke(new BasicStroke(stroke, BasicStroke.CAP_ROUND, BasicStroke.JOIN_MITER));
         g2d.setStroke(new BasicStroke(stroke, BasicStroke.CAP_ROUND, BasicStroke.JOIN_ROUND));         
         //g2d.setStroke(new BasicStroke(stroke, BasicStroke.CAP_SQUARE, BasicStroke.JOIN_BEVEL));
         //g2d.setStroke(new BasicStroke(stroke, BasicStroke.CAP_SQUARE, BasicStroke.JOIN_MITER));
         //g2d.setStroke(new BasicStroke(stroke, BasicStroke.CAP_SQUARE, BasicStroke.JOIN_ROUND));  

         g2d.draw(outline);

         g2d.setColor(textColor);
         g2d.fill(outline);

         g2d.dispose();

         return img;
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried to reproduce and don't see any gaps. Added `ImageIO.write(labelImg, "jpg", new File("c:/temp/test.jpg"));`. Tried both ways and don't see the artifacts. Java 8/Windows. You can also try rendering hint RenderingHints.KEY_TEXT_ANTIALIASING

Comment: @StanislavL Hmm - I'm on Java 8/Windows 10 Home, but I wouldn't expect it to have much of a difference. I just tried all the RenderingHints.KEY_TEXT_ANTIALIASING options and none of them seem to make a difference in this case. Can you share the output image you generated?

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/GlAKW the image i got

Comment: @StanislavL - ok so it seems like it doesn't happen with Helvetica or Dialog (both SansSerif fonts), can you try using a serif font like TimesRoman or Courier?

Comment: Tried TimesRoman from your example and Dialog and Courier. Don't see the effect

Comment: @StanislavL do you mind posting the image you had again as output with TimesRoman or Courier?